# How to see the full info of a handle in IDA debugger, just like other debuggers like xdbg?

Tags: ida, debugging, ollydbg

So in xdb, whenever i see a handle value like 0xA0, i can easily go to handle tabs and see what type of handle it is and for example if its a file handle, what file.

how can i do this in IDA debugger? tried googling but couldn't find any good answer.

Comment: What information are you trying to get?

Comment: @tmr232 path of the file corresponding to the handle

Comment: I don't think IDA's debugger has any OS-level utilities.